# Cannot get jpeg support with PIL on OSX

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

I'm trying to run Google App Engine with the PIL library & jpeg support in order to make use of the images module in GAE.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. I downloaded the tarball for `PIL 1.1.7` and extracted it and installed it with `python setup.py install`. However I noticed that the output said no jpeg support available. So I poked through the `README` and learned that I need to install libjpeg.
2. So then I downloaded the source for `jpeg-7` and built it. I configured with the following flags before I ran `make` and `make install`: `configure --enable-shared --enable static`. I originally configured & built without these flags but I found numerous sources claiming it needs to be done to get PIL to recognize libjpeg on OSX, so I ran `make clean` and `make distclean` and reconfigured with the flags and rebuilt.
3. Then I tried to re-install PIL. I navigated to the directory where I had extracted PIL's source code. In setup.py, I changed the line `JPEG_ROOT` to point to `/usr/local/bin` (where  jpeg had installed, but seeing that PIL wanted the libraries rather than the binaries I later repeated step 3 but with `/usr/local/lib` and again with `libinclude('/usr/local')` as a final attempt) and ran `python setup.py clean`, `python setup.py build`, and `python setup.py install`. This seemed to work fine. The output claimed that there was jpeg support. However, when I fired up GAE, PIL worked fine but I couldn't get jpeg support. The output from the PIL install script is here:

--

```
Jays-MacBook-Air:Imaging-1.1.7 jay$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
gcc-4.2 not found, using clang instead
--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      darwin 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43)
              [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To add a missing option, make sure you have the required
library, and set the corresponding ROOT variable in the
setup.py script.

To check the build, run the selftest.py script.
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pilconvert.py to 755
changing mode of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pildriver.py to 755
changing mode of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pilfile.py to 755
changing mode of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pilfont.py to 755
changing mode of /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pilprint.py to 755
running install_egg_info
Removing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7.egg-info
creating /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL.pth
```

But GAE claimed no jpeg support, and every time I ran `python selftest.py` it gave me the following output:

```
Jays-MacBook-Air:Imaging-1.1.7 jay$ python selftest.py
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 TEST SUMMARY 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from ./PIL
Binary modules loaded from ./PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok
--- TKINTER support ok
*** JPEG support not installed
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok
*** FREETYPE2 support not installed
*** LITTLECMS support not installed
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Running selftest:
*****************************************************************
Failure in example:
try:
 _info(Image.open(os.path.join(ROOT, "Images/lena.jpg")))
except IOError, v:
 print v
from line #24 of selftest.testimage
Expected: ('JPEG', 'RGB', (128, 128))
Got: decoder jpeg not available
1 items had failures:
   1 of  57 in selftest.testimage
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
*** 1 tests of 57 failed.
```

I am at my wit's end here. I've tried everything I can think of. I even tried pointing `setup.py` straight to the uncompiled header files of jpeg-7, since the comments in `setup.py` ask for the `lib` and `includes` directories. I simply can't figure out why PIL won't build with JPEG support. I've tried everything I can find on the internet. I seem to run into this kind of issue often when building from source. I would appreciate any and all suggestions (even suggestions on how to install PIL from a repository or something easy - I'm tired of trying to build software from source and ending up with huge messes of directories on my machine that won't compile into something nice).

Comment: what is the output of 'import PIL; PIL.__file__'? Is it the same as the place where you installed the PIL with jpeg support?

Comment: Additionally, have you considered using macports which will allow you to just invoke 'sudo port install py27-pil'? It's not a direct solution though.

Comment: Takashi - yes, they are the same. Running `import PIL` in an interactive Python session works just fine (except jpeg support of course). I have considered using Macports though I did manage to get everything working (see my own answer below). I figure one of these days, with all this software I keep needing to build, I might as well suck it up and install MacPorts.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure this out. I feel a little bit embarrassed, but hopefully this will be a reference to anybody doing this in the future.

It turns out that when I ran `python setup.py build` (or `setup.py install` without building first, which seems to call the build script if it hasn't been run already), it wouldn't overwrite the builds that already existed, and `setup.py clean` did not remove these either (though I naively assumed that the script did). I simply `rm -rf *`'d everything in the PIL `build/` folder, which forced PIL to start builds anew. Then finally PIL listened to me and applied the changes I made to `JPEG_ROOT`, which worked after all.